# Power series convergence to an exponential function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Can someone help me to show the proof of the following:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \big(\frac{a^n}{n!}\big)^{1/2} \le 2 e^{a}.$$

where $a \ge 0$.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just square the LHS and exploit the log-convexity of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you for the hint. Could you please elaborate on log-convexity of $\Gamma$ function. This part is new to me. Detailed steps would help a lot.

Comment: You should say $a\ge 0.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks. Clarified. Any help with the proof, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}=1$, we can use Jensen's Inequality to get a better bound:
$$
\begin{align}
a^{1/2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{a^n}{n!}\right)^{1/2}
&=a^{1/2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\left(\frac{n(n-1)\,a^n}{(n-2)!}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\le a^{1/2}+\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\frac{n(n-1)\,a^n}{(n-2)!}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=a^{1/2}+\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a^n}{(n-2)!}\right)^{1/2}\\[6pt]
&=a^{1/2}+ae^{a/2}\\[12pt]
&\lt2e^a-\frac74
\end{align}
$$

---

For the last inequality, because $\frac a2\le e^{a/2}-1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
2e^a-ae^{a/2}-a^{1/2}
&\ge2e^a-2\!\left(e^{a/2}-1\right)\!e^{a/2}-a^{1/2}\\[3pt]
&=2e^{a/2}-a^{1/2}\\
&\ge\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)^{-1/2}\!\!-\,\,\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)^{1/2}\\[3pt]
&\doteq1.76310333146\\
&\gt\frac74
\end{align}
$$
since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\left(2e^{a/2}-a^{1/2}\right)=e^{a/2}-\frac1{2a^{1/2}}=0$ when $a=\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)$, where $\operatorname{W}$ is [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: That's such an elegant proof. Can you elaborate on how you obtain the first inequality? I believe it has to do with Jensen's inequality, but cannot see it clearly. I look forward to your clarification with eager.

Comment: Also, I do not see where and how you have used the first convergence result (i.e., $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}=1$) in the proof. Please clarify.

Comment: Jensen's inequality says that, for a convex function $f$, if $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty w_n=1$$ then $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty w_nf\left(x_n\right) \ge f\!\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty w_nx_n\right)$$ In the proof, we use $w_n=\frac1{n(n-1)}$, $f(x)=x^2$, and $x_n=\left(\frac{n(n-1)\,a^n}{(n-2)!}\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: This is so brilliant solution @robjohn. Thank you. I have upvoted this and will wait if someone else has any alternative approaches (e.g., use of log-convexity of $\Gamma$ function).

Comment: Also, @robjohn, do you mind if I use your approach in my technical report? This is needed to complete my long proof. As far as acknowledgment to you is concerned, I do not think I can refer website (MSE) in my paper since only publications are permitted usually. Please let me know.

Comment: @ems: if you're going to use this, it is required by the [Creative Commons License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) to cite this post. Most bibliographies in journals today include URLs. Even though URLs are mostly transient, MSE URLs are more or less permanent.

Comment: thank for letting me know @robjohn about CCL which I wasn't familiar with. i will keep that in mind in case I use it in my report.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer with a better bound using LambertW. Could you @robjohn clarify why the transition from $2e^{a/2}-a^{1/2}$ to the next step $\ge\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)^{-1/2}\!\!-\,\,\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)^{1/2}$ has $\ge$ instead of $=$.

Comment: As explained in the line following that series of (in)equalities, $2e^{a/2}-a^{1/2}$ reaches a minimum at $a=\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)$, so $2e^{a/2}-a^{1/2}\ge\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)^{-1/2}\!\!-\,\,\operatorname{W}\!\left(\frac14\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: thank you @robjohn. you have taught me many invaluable math tools in this single problem that I initially found in some technical paper. your proof is very insightful on many levels. thanks again. i have accepted your answer and upvoted it.

Comment: Actually the constant $\color{red}{2}$ can be lowered down to $\sqrt{2}$ with elementary methods and down to $1$ with probabilistic arguments.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Indeed, $a^{1/2}+ae^{a/2}\lt e^a$, so the bound shown above shows that, too. I've plotted it, but I will work on a proof.

Comment: I think the above use of Jensen's inequality for the $\le$ inequality is not applicable here since $\sqrt{x}$ is not convex. I used Cauchy-Schwartz inequality instead to prove the result different from @robjohn approach.

Comment: @ems: $f(x)=x^2$ is convex.  That is what I used. The inequality I used is the square root of the following:

Comment: $$ \left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\left(\frac{n(n-1)\,a^n}{(n-2)!}\right)^{1/2}\right)^2 \le\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\frac{n(n-1)\,a^n}{(n-2)!} $$

Answer (score 2):

Following the approach suggested in the hint (and assuming $a>0$),

$$\left[\sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{\frac{a^n}{n!}}\right]^2 =\sum_{n,m\geq 1}\frac{a^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}{\sqrt{m!n!}}=\sum_{h\geq 2}a^{h/2}\sum_{k=1}^{h-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k!(h-k)!}}$$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the (midpoint-)log-convexity of $\Gamma$ we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{h-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k!(h-k)!}}\leq\sqrt{(h-1)\frac{2^h-2}{h!}}\leq \frac{2^{h/2}}{(h/2)!}$$
hence

$$\left[\sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{\frac{a^n}{n!}}\right]^2\leq \sum_{h\geq 2}\frac{(2a)^{h/2}}{(h/2)!}\leq e^{2a}\left[1+\text{Erf}(\sqrt{2a})\right]\leq 2e^{2a} $$
and by extracting the square root of both sides
$$\boxed{ \sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{\frac{a^n}{n!}} \leq \color{red}{\sqrt{2}\,e^a}.}$$

---

**Explanations**: the first equation is just a rearrangement of an absolutely convergent double series. The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) is used in the form $$\sum a_n \leq \sqrt{\sum 1 \sum a_n^2}$$ and [the log-convexity of $\Gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) is used to state $\frac{h-1}{h!}\leq\frac{1}{(h/2)!^2}$. At last, the series $\sum_{h\geq 2}\frac{z^{h/2}}{(h/2)!}$ [has a closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800364/taylor-series-integration) only depending on the exponential function and the error function (which is bounded by $1$). By disregarding negative terms and simplifying we reach the highlighted conclusion. Actually a more accurate estimation of $\sum_{k=1}^{h-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k!(h-k)!}}$ (for instance through the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)) allows us to prove the sharper inequality
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{\frac{a^n}{n!}} \leq \color{red}{e^a}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer @JackD'Aurizio. Tbh, I find each step of yours difficult to understand due to 'my limited math skills'. Do you mind inserting more details into how you go to each next step of equality/inequality? I believe this would also help reach a wider math audience.

Comment: @ems: I moved the requested explanations into the answer above.

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio. There are many invaluable math tricks to learn from your answer and moreover you have a much tighter inequality. Insightful!