# Sum : $f(x) = \sum_n \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is it possible to find a sum of a series:

$$f(x) = \sum_n \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$$

at least as a combination of some special functions?

Comment: You might be out of luck when [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bx%5En%2FSqrt%5Bn!%5D,%7Bn,0,Infinity%7D%5D&wal=header) has no idea. There might be a chance, though.

Comment: There is no known closed form for that series.  You can name it the Ilya function and publish a paper on its interesting properties (if there are any, which I doubt).

Comment: Did this arise from the quantum harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to calculate the "coherence" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0275), which is the sum of non-diagonals of the density matrix, of an actual coherent state.

Comment: No way, but the first terms of asymptotic behaviour of $f(x)$ (for $x\to +\infty$) can be simply computed by squaring both sides.

Comment: >> "first terms of asymptotic behaviour of f(x) (for x→+∞) can be simply computed by squaring both sides", @JackD'Aurizio, can you, please, show this in more detail?

Comment: @Ilya: have a look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510830/44121

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments the function $f(x)$ does not have a closed form, however I'll post here my way of finding its asymptotic behaviour at $x \to \infty$, in case it is useful to anyone.

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} \sum_n \frac{x^n }{\sqrt{n!}}n.$$
Suppose that $f'(x) =\frac{1}{x}g(x) f(x)$.
$$g(x)=\frac{\sum \frac{x^n }{\sqrt{n!}}n}{\sum \frac{x^n }{\sqrt{n!}}}$$
Using the fact that:
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a_n x^n}{b_n x^n} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n},$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{x^2}=\frac{\sum \frac{x^n }{\sqrt{n!}}n}{\sum \frac{x^{n+2} }{\sqrt{n!}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} =1$$
Therefore $g(x) = x^2 + o(x^2)$.
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) - x^2 =\frac{\sum \frac{x^n }{\sqrt{n!}}n -\sum \frac{x^{n+2} }{\sqrt{n!}} }{\sum \frac{x^{n} }{\sqrt{n!}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} n -\sqrt{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$
Therefore $g(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{2}+o(1)$. Now we have a simple differential equation:
$$f' = \left(x + \frac{1}{2x}\right)f,$$ which gives the answer:
$$f \sim \sqrt{x}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}},  \, x\to \infty$$ 
Next terms of the approximation of $g(x)$ will be $\sim c/x^k$, $k>1$ which gives multipliers of $\exp(c/x^{k+1})$ in $f$, which quickly goes to 1.